# Map JSON to php object

Tags: php, json, deserialization, jms-serializer

I have a JSON which has the following structure, but I am only interested in the data inside `entries` node, therefore my DTO class's fields mirrors the tags inside the said node. But as expected I get an error when deserializing the JSON since JMSserializer expects an object which contains fields for all the tags in the JSON. Is there a way I can ignore the other tags? What is the proper way to accomplish this?

```
 {
"result": {
    "data": {
        "provider": "facebook",
        "pages": {
            "pagination": {
                "current_page": 1,
                "total_pages": 1,
                "entries_per_page": 250,
                "total_entries": 2,
                "order": {
                    "field": "date_creation",
                    "direction": "desc"
                }
            },
            "count": 2,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "user_token": "48d6b4a9-afd7-4ee7-b359-45bbf618ebe9",
                    "identity_token": "f5148587-3925-4fec-a214-3a339a023d2b",
                    "page_token": "c66c2d03-c9de-485b-9aea-445c405d44ab",
                    "date_creation": "Tue, 07 Apr 2015 10:37:52  0200",
                    "name": "Test Page",
                    "description": "This is the description of the page.",
                    "category": "Community",
                    "num_likes": 27,
                    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/test-page",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?type=square",
                    "pictureUrl": "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?type=large",
                    "source": {
                        "identifier": 1234567890,
                        "access_token": {
                            "key": "E797C0013811A1D1E35AD7EDD10FB99986DB664B0996C76ED9AE5E0A5151BBF9E797C0013811A1D1E35AD7EDD10FB99986DB664B0996C76ED9AE5E0A5151BBF9"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "user_token": "1f178827-c746-43e0-84d0-75cfd0513b1e",
                    "identity_token": "462fae22-f46b-4343-838c-1fc35113e92c",
                    "page_token": "886a4c73-fa1a-4261-839f-42672f42b842",
                    "date_creation": "Tue, 07 Apr 2015 10:37:52  0200",
                    "name": "Another Test Page",
                    "description": "This is the description of the page.",
                    "category": "Computers/internet website",
                    "num_likes": 2119,
                    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/another-test-page",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "https://graph.facebook.com/987654321/picture?type=square",
                    "pictureUrl": "https://graph.facebook.com/987654321/picture?type=large",
                    "source": {
                        "identifier": 987654321,
                        "access_token": {
                            "key": "A21C619251FB098250A15A69B20BEE6ED6835149CE1496D78A674F11B0920F9FA21C619251FB098250A15A69B20BEE6ED6835149CE1496D78A674F11B0920F9F"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode` ?

Comment: @Burki I am trying to map it to an object, that's why using JMSserializer.

Comment: You might still `json_decode` , then extract the part you need, and if you can't come up with a better idea, `json_encode` the part that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` for that:

```
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);
$entries = $arr['result']['data']['pages']['entries'];
print_r($entries);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_token] => 48d6b4a9-afd7-4ee7-b359-45bbf618ebe9
            [identity_token] => f5148587-3925-4fec-a214-3a339a023d2b
            [page_token] => c66c2d03-c9de-485b-9aea-445c405d44ab
            [date_creation] => Tue, 07 Apr 2015 10:37:52  0200
            [name] => Test Page
            [description] => This is the description of the page.
            [category] => Community
            [num_likes] => 27
            [link] => https://www.facebook.com/test-page
            [thumbnailUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?type=square
            [pictureUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture?type=large
            [source] => Array
                (
                    [identifier] => 1234567890
                    [access_token] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => E797C0013811A1D1E35AD7EDD10FB99986DB664B0996C76ED9AE5E0A5151BBF9E797C0013811A1D1E35AD7EDD10FB99986DB664B0996C76ED9AE5E0A5151BBF9
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_token] => 1f178827-c746-43e0-84d0-75cfd0513b1e
            [identity_token] => 462fae22-f46b-4343-838c-1fc35113e92c
            [page_token] => 886a4c73-fa1a-4261-839f-42672f42b842
            [date_creation] => Tue, 07 Apr 2015 10:37:52  0200
            [name] => Another Test Page
            [description] => This is the description of the page.
            [category] => Computers/internet website
            [num_likes] => 2119
            [link] => https://www.facebook.com/another-test-page
            [thumbnailUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/987654321/picture?type=square
            [pictureUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/987654321/picture?type=large
            [source] => Array
                (
                    [identifier] => 987654321
                    [access_token] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => A21C619251FB098250A15A69B20BEE6ED6835149CE1496D78A674F11B0920F9FA21C619251FB098250A15A69B20BEE6ED6835149CE1496D78A674F11B0920F9F
                        )

                )

        )

)
```